# SQL Server 2008 R2 linkedServer to Oracle 12c

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, oracle12c, linked-server, odb

We have integrated system , what we are doing in the integration process is our invoices data is going to insert in the oracle ebs R12 (oracle database 12c) through SQL Server linked Server using ODBC driver but when this process starts on the sql server with the help of sql server agent service, then process shows **preemptive_com_getdata** wait type and the sql server consume all the available RAM on the server and then OS start hanging even task manager takes time to open and then finally sql server services restart automatically

This issue occurring after upgraded on the Oracle 12c but there is no any complaint from the Oracle database side

Second thing is that we observed that ping from sql server to oracle 12c database is giving sometime request time out

SQL Server 2008 R2 with SP3 on Windows Server 2008 R2,Oracle Database 12c (12.1.0.1) on IBM AIX 6.1 TL9,Oracle Driver version (12.2) ,

What was the reason behind this ?